# NGINX return correct headers with custom error documents

Tags: nginx

I've set up NGINX to return custom error documents for my proxied server, it shows the correct file but always returns a `200 OK` header.

The relevant NGINX config is

```
server {
    listen       94.23.155.32:80;
    server_name  rmg.io www.rmg.io;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://rmgshort/;
    }

    error_page 404 = /error/404.html;
error_page 500 501 502 503 503 = /error/500.html;

    location /error/ {
        root /var/rmg/;
    }
}
```

You can test this if you want, [this page](http://rmg.io/notfoundpage) should return a 404 error, it returns the correct document but changes the status code to '200 OK' (Test HTTP headers [here](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/http-header-viewer.shtml?url=http://rmg.io/notfoundpage)), if I replace `root /var/rmg/` with `internal;` the correct header is returned but then my custom error page doesn't work.

How do I get NGINX to return my custom error document with the correct status header?

I'm running NGINX 1.0.4 on RHEL 6.1

Comment: RedHat 6.0, or RHEL 6.0?

Comment: @womble RHEL 6.1, sorry I just always refer to it as RedHat =)

Comment: @womble Also not sure why I put 6.0 in the question #facepalm

Comment: I don't think it actually matters here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drop the `=` out of the `error_page` directive; you can specify any return code you like with `=NNN` (eg `=401`), but if you give a bare `=` it means "use the error code of the error handler", which for a static file will always be "200 OK".  Without any `=`, you'll get the original error code returned.

Irritatingly, a straightforward reading of [the (otherwise) fine manual](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) (as at the time of writing this answer, anyway) might make you think that it's the other way around (`=` keeps the original return code), but local testing indicates that it definitely works the way I've described above.

Comment: This is not completely accurate. A bare `=` means that Nginx will use the returned status code of the designated error handler. Meaning if you do `error_page 404 = /handler.php`and your `handler.php` script returns 200 then it uses 200, if `handler.php` returns 409 then it uses 409. I agree, though, that the wiki entry is worded poorly and I'll try to clarify it a bit.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the clarification; I've never actually used a non-static error handler (and obviously a non-existent error handler's pointless), so I'd never come across a situation where the return code would be non-200.  I've updated my answer accordingly.